# how to make Zurb Foundation non-responsive?

Tags: frameworks, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I have made a website with Foundation-master wordpress theme, it looks good but I dont like how its behaving in other browser widths. Is there a way of making it non-responsive, or fixed to a certain width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation was built to simply create responsive websites.
Beside of the question why you use this framework if you don't want a responsive webseite, it's only possible if you start removing all the media queries in foundation css and by removing the viewport meta tag.

Maybe you should better invest this time to make your webseite responsive so that it also fits on smaller screens and mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you. I know, I should have kept with 960.gs, it just got too complicated for me, making all the elements responsive.

You solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's necessary to deactivate the responsive features. For example if, like it happened to me twice already, a website is launching non-responsive and the optimization for smartphones/tablets is added later.

Foundation is an awesome framework even if you take out the responsiveness. The SCSS files are very well structured it comes with a library of very useful UI elements. It's a great choice for responsive and non-responsive sites if you ask me. Some people might also want to streamline their workflow and not jump between different frameworks depending on the project to keep costs low.

Anyways, here my two cents. This deactivated all responsiveness for me:

```
.row {  
     width: 62.5rem;
}
```

And then in the _settings.scss

```
$small-range: (0, 90em);
$medium-range: (0, 90em);
$large-range: (0, 90em);
```

This way we're essentially always seeing the large version. As far as I can tell this even works for top bar etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is marked as answered, I just wanted to give you a quick hint to prevent the Foundation 4 grid to act responsive, since we had also to deal with that.

In our case (SASS version) setting the width of the `<body>` element via css to the specific width of the grid and reducing the breakpoint in the SASS variable `$small-screen` to 1px worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a min-width in the body attributes like this:

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%; 
  min-width: <value A>;
  max-width: <value A>;
  width: 100%;
}
```

(foundation.css)